# Weekday. How to fix this error in the following code?

Tags: javascript

Two lines of the form "03 November 2017 04:17" are passed to the "testDateTime"function.
You need to convert strings to dates, compare them. For more get a day of the week.. Sunday - Saturday : 0 - 6

Sample Input:

19 October 1909 10:27

28 March 1909 00:59

Sample Output:
Tuesday

```
function testDateTime(a, b){
  var arr = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  var aa = Date.parse(a);
  var bb = Date.parse(b);
  var i = ( aa > bb ? a.getDay() : b.getDay());
 return arr[i];
}

||

function testDateTime(a, b) {    
  var arr = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  var aa = Date.parse(a);
  var bb = Date.parse(b);
  var i = ( aa > bb ? aa.getDay(a) : bb.getDay(b));
 return arr[i];
}
```

Sample Input:
19 October 1909 10:27
28 March 1909 00:59

Sample Output:
Tuesday

Error: i is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Mozilla documentation for Date.parse():

> The Date.parse() method parses a string representation of a date, and
>   returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC
>   or NaN if the string is unrecognized or, in some cases, contains
>   illegal date values (e.g. 2015-02-31).

So the above code can never work because you are calling .getDate() on a string variable. You can only call it on a Date object. In the first example, you try to call `a.getDate()` where `a` is "19 October 1909 10:27" (a string).

In the second example, you call .getDate() on `aa` which is the result of `Date.parse()`. As described above, the .getDate() function returns a string, so the effect is the same - calling a non existing method on a string variable.

Try this instead:

```js
function testDateTime(a, b){
  var arr = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  var aa = new Date(Date.parse(a));
  var bb = new Date(Date.parse(b));
  var i = ( aa > bb ? aa.getDay() : bb.getDay());
 return arr[i];
}

console.log(testDateTime('19 October 1909 10:27', '28 March 1909 00:59'));
```

Output:
`Tuesday`

Comment: The problem in the second code is not caused by `.getDate()` returning a string (which is not true), but that `Date.parse` returns an integer.